# How can I use a Nikkor mikro on a full frame DSLR to photograph 35 mm film and slides?

Tags: lens-adapter, full-frame, film-scanner, nikon-d800

I have a Nikon D800 and a Nikkor mikro 105 mm (old version, no VR) and I would like to scan 35 mm film and slides.

I see that film adaptors meant for macro lenses usually require 55-60 mm lenses, for example the [Nikon ES-2 Film Digitizing Adapter Set](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1357884-REG/nikon_27192_es_2_film_digitalizing_adapet.html) works with a 40 mm macro lens if used on APS-C and with a 50-60 mm macro lens when used on full frame.

What can I do to use my equipment and still scan film/slides with minimal cropping? I'm not sure it can help, but I am able to 3D print adaptors if needed.

Comment: Can you link to a film adapter you're referring to? Have you researched the likes of this? https://www.negative.supply/gettingstarted

Comment: Related: [What lens should I use to be able to fill the frame with a mounted 35mm slide at 12 inches?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/51906/15871) and [What is the best focal length for using a DSLR to digitize film negatives?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/112645/15871) and [Which DSLR macro setup to buy for scanning negatives?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/81866/15871) and [Does a filter exist to color-correct color negatives when copying them with a DSLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/23942/15871)

Comment: Also related: [What is the best way to get good quality digital pictures from negatives?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/39183/15871) and [What are the major differences when digitizing slides/negatives with a DSLR vs. a scanner?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/11510/15871) and [How to convert old school photo slides to a digital format?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/27909/15871) and [Best option for scanning a large volume of slides](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/34398/15871)

Comment: @osullic that website is interesting!

Comment: I didn't intend my comment to specifically be an endorsement of Negative Supply. I'm sure they have good quality solutions, but they're not the only option. Compare for example [Valoi](https://www.valoi.co/camera-scanning).

Comment: @osullic yes that solution is interesting in general but the lens adapter may be enough for the intended use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ES-2 used with the longest adaptor provided is still too short for the 105mm Nikkor micro, as stated by Nikon after all which didn't list it as compatible.

I 3D printed a 70 mm filter (not lens!) extension tube M62x0.75 to match the minimum distance with the film holder and it works perfectly.

The image here shows the idea, even if the actual extension tube I printed it was three times as long, the one in photo is a test but it's the only photo I have.

[image: camera with 3D printed extension tube]

Answer (score 1):

"Scanning" would typically involve using a scanner, not a DSLR.

The only thing you need is an extension tube of some sort to position the slide at a distance to where it fits w/in the lens' FOV.

[**Cheap extension tubes and couple of adapting rings**](https://nikonrumors.com/2018/05/12/slide-copying-with-the-nikon-es-1-br-5-adapters-and-the-nikkor-micro-af-s-105mm-f-2-8-ed-vr-lens.aspx/) to allow attaching the tubes in front of the lens will work. Or any multitude of DIY setups can work... [it doesn't even have to be attached](https://www.diyphotography.net/how-to-build-a-diy-35mm-slides-and-negatives-copying-machine/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about something like this:

[image]

If your lens is really a macro lens (which means it can project things on the sensor at their actual physical size), then you can use it to project a 24x36mm slide/negative on your full-frame 24x36mm sensor.

Adapters were mostly meant for people with APS-C cameras on which the standard macro lens is a 6Omm one, and the lens-to-film distance is around 80mm. And as far as I can tell on my 100mm macro lens the lens-to-object distance for 1:1 projection on the sensor is around 150mm.

But you can also use these copiers with a standard lens:

- The copier can come with a built-in close-up lens (the one in the picture has one, the big ring at the end is a removable close-up lens))
- You can use macro extension rings to transform a regular lens into a macro one

Comment: actually the ES-2 I linked comes with different mounting adaptors depending on the lens used. The longest adaptor is meant to be used with the NIKKOR Z MC 50mm f/2.8 which has a minimum focusing distance of ... 160 mm. Using that adaptor with the 105 mm may get closer to 1:1, likely about 1:1.06 which is also fine.

Comment: The resolution of your camera vastly exceeds what you get from most film, so some cropping shouldn't be a problem if ever...

Comment: The ES-2 used with the longest adaptor provided is still too short for the 105mm Nikkor micro. I 3D printed a 70 mm filter (not lens!) extension tube M62x0.75 and it works perfectly.